# Tell AppleScript To Build XCode Project

Tags: xcode, applescript

The following are the steps I would like to have:

1. launch xcode
2. open a specific xcodeproj file
3. build and debug it
4. quit xcode

The following is my first attempt to write AppleScript:

```
tell application "Xcode"
    tell project "iphone_manual_client"
        debug
    end tell
    close project "iphone_manual_client"
end tell
```

This only works when xcode has this project opened. I would like to have the project to be opened only when it is necessary to do so.

Can any AppleScript gurus out there points me to the right direction? Thanks.

-chuan-

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think I managed to solve it. The following is the AppleScript:

```
tell application "Xcode"
    open "Users:chuan:Desktop:iphone_manual_client:iphone_manual_client.xcodeproj"
    tell project "iphone_manual_client"
            clean
            build
            (* for some reasons, debug will hang even the debug process has completed. 
               The try block is created to suppress the AppleEvent timeout error 
             *)
            try
                debug
            end try
    end tell
    quit
end tell
```

The path has to be in format of ":" instead of "/". The only problem now is that after the debug console has done its job, AppleScript seems to "hang" as though waiting for something to happen. I need to do more research on AppleScript to know what is wrong with the script.

Comment: do you know how to check if debug is already running? I'm getting an issue on subsequent executions of my script: "Unable to debug executable since a debug session is in progress"

Comment: Hi Aaron, I supposed another option is to force XCode to shutdown completely and launch XCode again before running your new set of tests? This might get around the problem you are facing.

Comment: Unfortunately a lot of Xcode AppleScript functionality was broken with Xcode 4, including the run and debug features. It looks like the script above no longer works.

Comment: You must remove `project` word in `tell project` command.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure about AppleScript but you can compile it from command line, without opening xcode ide, like this:

```
xcodebuild -configuration Debug -target WhatATool -project WhatATool.xcodeproj
```

Where configuration is obvious option, target is the name in Target list of xcode and the project name at the end.

Comment: Hi stefan, 
   thanks for your response. This will build the application. The reason why I need to use xcode is the uploading and remote debugging  mechanism it has for iphone. There is no command line tool that I can use to let me upload my newly compiled iphone app to the real device easily apart from xcode.

Answer (score 2):

There's a command line utility called `xcodebuild` (man page [here](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/xcodebuild.1.html)) which may work better for what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Hi pgb, xcodebuild will only build it for me. It does not help me to upload the app to iphone and debug it from there.

Answer (score 2):

Since debugging can take an arbitrary amount of time, you probably want a "with timeout of  seconds" / "end timeout" block around the debug message.