# How to build & run Xcode with Applescript?

Tags: xcode, applescript

I'm trying to emulate Xcode's ⌘-R keystroke in another editor (namely, Vim); I thought I would be able to do this with some shell scripting & applescript, but it doesn't seem to be working correctly:

```
open -a Xcode "MyProj.xcodeproj"
osascript -e 'tell app "Xcode"' -e 'build' -e 'launch' -e 'end tell'
```

The problem with this is it launches the app regardless of whether Xcode reports errors. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tell AppleScript To Build XCode Project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007082/tell-applescript-to-build-xcode-project)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I use:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Xcode"
    activate

    set targetProject to active workspace document
    if (build targetProject) is equal to "Build succeeded" then
        launch targetProject
    end if
end tell'
```

Of course, the project has to already be open in Xcode for this to work. (I'd rather not hard code the current project into my script)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work any more with Xcode 4.6: "Xcode got an error: Can’t get active project document." Though, of course, a buildable project is open in Xcode.

Comment: With XCode 5 I get "107:126: execution error: Xcode got an error: The specified object is a property, not an element. (-10008)"

Comment: In Xcode 5 replace "active project document" with "active workspace document"

Answer (score 1):

Unless you really want the Xcode GUI, you could just use xcodebuild instead of launching and scripting Xcode.

Comment: I know about xcodebuild, but I wanted to get this to work in the GUI, mainly because of the error list that brings you to the line of the error when double-clicked.

Answer (score 0):

And for other TextMate users out there, a cobbled together.. improved version by mashing it together with the existing 'Open project in Xcode..' command:

```
PROJECT=$(ruby -- "${TM_BUNDLE_SUPPORT}/bin/find_xcode_project.rb")
if [[ -f "${PROJECT}/project.pbxproj" ]]; then
   open -a Xcode "${PROJECT}"
else
   echo "Didn't find an Xcode project file."
   echo "You may want to set TM_XCODE_PROJECT."
fi


osascript -e 'tell application "Xcode"
    activate

    set targetProject to project of active project document
    if (build targetProject) is equal to "Build succeeded" then
        launch targetProject
    end if
end tell'
```