# AppleScript to build on multiple iOS devices within Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, applescript

I'm wanting to automate the build of my iPhone apps across multiple devices (all connected at once) within Xcode, but I can't work out how to use AppleScript to select which device to build on.

From within Xcode (version 3.2.4) you can select the device to build/debug on by changing the Active Executable (Project>Set Active Executable) to match the name of your device but  creating a new Active Executable in AppleScript (set e to make new executable with properties {name:"app - device", path:"build/Release-iphoneos/app.app"} simply creates a new executable and attempts to launch it on the machine (not the device, not even the simulator). Is there somewhere else I can make the selection of which device to run on?

I'm really sick of having to constantly change the active executable to change between the iPad, retina display and non-retina display, this would allow me to build upon a device of my choosing with a script.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[This question has already been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007082/tell-applescript-to-build-xcode-project); Applescript isn't the entire solution here. You need also take a look at the `xcodebuild` command in Terminal

```
xcodebuild -configuration myChosenConfig -target myTarget -project myAppProject.xcodeproj
```

You can easily fold in the command into an Applescript using the `do shell script` command.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. I had looked at that question but it only seems to result in building the project and not moving the app onto the device of my choosing.  Basically when I run: osascript tell application "System Events" key code 15 using {command down, option down} end tell (equivalent to pressing run>run from the xcode menu), I want it to be able to also select which of the devices to run on at the moment it defaults to the previously used device.  Hope that makes sense.  Once again thanks.