# AppleScript click "run" in Xcode

Tags: xcode, applescript

I have never used AppleScript before, but I am trying to write a script that will open Xcode and run the correct app on the correct simulator.  Unfortunately I keep stumbling into syntax errors and I am somewhat baffled by the documentation (for a language designed to be like English, it's giving me more trouble than it's worth).  I figured out how to open Xcode with the "Activate" command, but am stuck on how to click a specific button.  From what I understand I should be able to say something like `click button 1 of group 1 of window 1` or something like that, but not only is that giving me syntax errors (as are the many variants I've tried), but also I don't know how to figure out which window is window 1, which group is group 1, etc.  I tried using the Accessibility Inspector but couldn't make heads or tails out of it.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**EDIT**
This is not a repeat of the linked question.  That question was about running a build command.  I want to actually click buttons in Xcode, and am trying to run the "run" command with the simulator.

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007082/tell-applescript-to-build-xcode-project

Comment: somehow I hadn't found that.  Looks like this might be a repost.  I'll try that and see how it goes.  Thanks!

Comment: So I took a look at that piece of code.  It seems to build my project successfully, but what I really want to do is choose a scheme and simulator and click the run button, which would be a different script with which I am still struggling.

Answer (score 9):

A quick and easy way is to simulate the keystroke:

```
tell application "Xcode"
    activate
    tell application "System Events"
        perform (keystroke "r" using command down)
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if I want to specify the scheme and simulator first?  Are there keystrokes for that?

Comment: I tried putting a compound `tell process "Xcode"` statement inside your `tell application "System Events"` statement with the line `click (pop up button whose description is "Active Scheme")`, but I got the error: `Can’t get pop up button whose description = "Active Scheme".`

Comment: (I chose `description is "Active Scheme"` because the button that brings up the pop up menu I want says it has AXDescription "Active Scheme."  Is that right?)

Comment: @Kvass you should be able to do this using Xcode's scripting terminology but it's a bit of a pain and my applescripting skills are not good… you can use Automator Record/Watch Me Do the steps if you want to script the UI. feel free to wait for a more complete answer.